# How to convert two intersected DFAs into a minimal DFA

Tags: intersection, dfa, deterministic, automaton

I have the following problem: There are two deterministic finite automatons which should be **intersected** and **converted** into a single **minimal deterministic finite automaton**. Is there an algorithm to do that?

[image: the two DFAs]

I know that I can create an NFA by creating the cartesian product of the two automatons and convert the outcome into a DFA, but this is a time-killing procedure. Is there an easier way to create the intersection of two automatons?

By the way: here is the solution:
[image: Solution]

I tried my approach as I described below, but I can't imagine how to get the solution: Computing the complement of the two DFA's gives my two new DFA's with exactly two accepting states. Now I have to combine them and minimize them, but wherefrom can I get the third accepting state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, there's no "direct" algorithm that accomplishes this. You can do this by

- minimizing the two input DFAs,
- computing their Cartesian product (which produces another DFA, by the way, not an NFA), then
- minimizing the result.

It's not strictly necessary to minimize the two input DFAs, but it can help with efficiency. If you have an n-state and an m-state DFA, their Cartesian product will have O(mn) states. The DFA minimization algorithm runs in time O(k<sup>2</sup>), where k is the number of states in the DFA, so if the original DFAs have sizes n and m, computing the Cartesian product and then minimizing will take time O(m<sup>2</sup>n<sup>2</sup>), whereas minimizing, then computing the Cartesian product, then minimizing again takes time O(m<sup>2</sup> + n<sup>2</sup> + m'<sup>2</sup>n'<sup>2</sup>), where m' and n' are the sizes of the minimized DFAs.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your ideas! I have to solve exercises like this by hand, what means computing the Cartesian product with O(3²) takes too much time. In the meantime I found a way to avoid intersecting the DFA's by unsing DeMorgan. I have to compute the complement of the two DFA's and combine them. Consequental, the steps would be 
- (minimize the input DFA's)
- compute their complements
- combine them
- minimize the result

Is this way also possible or did I miss something?